# Validator with grails : Failed to create the user

Tags: grails, validation, grails-validation

I have this:

```
class Usuario {

        String username
        String password
        String passwordDos
        String nombre
        String apellidoPaterno
        String apellidoMaterno
        Date fechaDeNacimiento
        String sexo
        String correo

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true, validator: { val, obj ->
                                            obj.password != val
                                            return ['usuario.userPassError'] 
                                        }
        password blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
                                                    obj.passwordDos == val
                                                        return ['usuario.passDiferentes']    
                                                }
                passwordDos blank: false
                nombre   blank: false, maxSize: 64
                apellidoPaterno blank: false, maxSize: 64
                apellidoMaterno blank: true, maxSize: 64
                sexo inList: ["Femenino", "Masculino"]
                correo   blank: false, maxSize: 128, email:true       
    }
}
```

I want to return in the error message, but I'm not doing wrong, I could explain alguein please?

Comment: what is the problem?  Are you trying to customize the validation messages?

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect there to be some sort of conditional return in the validator closures. As it stands, it looks like they'll always fail, returning the error code.

Try writing your custom validators like:

```
// username validator
validator: { val, obj ->
    obj.password == val ? 'userPassError' : true
}

// password validator
validator: { val, obj ->
    obj.passwordDos != val ? 'passDiferentes' : true
}
```

Note the different message codes that are being returned, too.

Then, make sure you have the following in your appropriate `grails-app/i18n/messages*` file(s):

```
usuario.username.userPassError = Username and password cannot be the same
usuario.password.passDiferentes = Password does not match password confirmation
```